# SQlite multiple IDs linking one to another table

Tags: sqlite

I have one table containing rows with information about dealers and unique IDs.

```
id    name
1     dealer1
2     dealer2
```

The other table contains products which are sometimes available at multiple dealers.

```
name     dealerids
product1 1, 2
product2 2
```

Now I would like to query all dealers a product is available at, but I don't know how. I tried something like:

```
SELECT * FROM dealers WHERE id IN (SELECT dealerids FROM products WHERE name = "product1")
```

which didn't work. I'm in C# and `dealerids` is based on a string and stored as `TEXT` in the database. I tried `"'1', '2'"` and `"1, 2"`, both didn't work for me.

I'm quiet new to SQL so is there a way to achieve what I want using the `TEXT` datatype?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, that's strange way to store the values in a database - as a string separated by commas. But if it's really the case and you can not change this to multiple lines where each record corresponds to one dealer id , you probably can try this:

```
select * from dealers where exists (select 1 from products where  name = "product1" and dealerids like 
dealers.id || ',' || '%') or exists
(select 1 from products where name = "product1" and dealerids like '%' || ', ' || dealers.id || ',%')
or exists 
(select 1 from products where name = "product1" and dealerids like '%, ' || dealeris.id)
```

The first clause is taking care of the case where desired delearid is the first one in the string, the second clause is for the case when it's in the middle, and the third one is for the ending id.

Comment: I'm not set on the dealerids beeing a string with comma-seperated values. Things would just be way easier for me if it could be some sort of string. If there is a different, "better looking" solution to this using a different datatype that would be fine too. What I definitly would want to avoid is having multiple rows for one product for each dealer it is available at.

Comment: OK.
If you can produce a string like '#1#2#3#', in such a way that the different ids are well separated and you will not get '10' while looking for 1 and you also have some sign at the beginning and at the end, then you can manage with one  clause only:
select * from dealers where exists (select 1 from products where  name = "product1" and dealerids like '%#' || dealers.id || '#%');
Is this "better looking"?

Answer (score 0):

A normalized database would look something like this, in your scenario.

```
// table_dealer
   id  name
   1   dealer1
   2   dealer2

// table_product
   id   title
   1    product1
   2    product2


//table_associate
   id     product_id    dealer_id
    1       1              1
    1       2              1
```

> Now I would like to query all dealers a product is available at, but I don't know how. I tried something like

```
  //searching by product_id
  select  dealer_id from table_associate where product_id = X

  Use JOIN query to get data from these 3 tables.
```